# How to loop through a DocumentSnapshot.data and retrieve id's and keys?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How do I loop through a DocumentSnapshot.data() object and retrieve its keys and values?
My code currently looks like this:

```
Future<void> drawPolygons() async {
    var points = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('polygons')
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        //if user has polygon data on account
        var data = documentSnapshot.data();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your `data` variable should be a [`Map` object](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html) with the field names as keys, and their values as values. Isn't it?

Comment: I get this type when I print it: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>. I tried converting it to a map but I get this error: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map' in type cast

Answer (score 2):

```
**Update Your Method and Convert the data to Map**
    
    
    Future<void> drawPolygons() async {
        var points = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('polygons')
            .doc(uid)
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
          if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          Map data = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map);
          for (var entry in data.values) {
             print(entry);
           }
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Map'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'.

Comment: I'm getting this : The getter 'entries' isn't defined for the type 'Map'.
Try importing the library that defines 'entries', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'entries'